# Importing variables from one file to another in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a personal project, this is my directory structure:

```
app/
-- function/
-- -- run.py
-- constants.py
```

I have some variables defined within `constants.py` and would like to import them and use them within `run.py`.

I have tried the following approaches, both seemed to fail:

```
from ..constants import VARIABLE
```

This one threw `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

```
from app.constants import VARIABLE
```

This one threw `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

I want to be able to read `VARIABLE` that's been defined in `constants.py` into `run.py` and use it there.

What should I do? I'm not looking for a workaround, I want something I can reproduce in multiple different projects.

Comment: Does each directory (including subdir) has `__init__.py`?

Comment: Is the `app` directory on your sys.path? If so, just use `from constants import VARIABLE`

Comment: Everything about modules becomes simpler once you stop thinking about importing from *files*. You import from modules, and you need to learn how modules are defined from files.

Comment: In particular, `run.py` not intended to define a module named `app.function.run`; it's a script that happens to live in the same directory that defines the `app.function` package.

Comment: @dinhanhx Including an empty `__init__.py` file within every dir & subdir still resulted in the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the module of your `app/` directory by creating an empty file name `__init__.py` in the `app/` directory. The `__init__.py` file tells the python interpreter that this is a module.

## The New Layout will be as Follows

```bash
app/
├── __init__.py
├── constants.py
└── functions/
    └── run.py
```

Now You can easily import the variables from the `constants.py` in `run.py` by

```py
from app.constants import VARIABLE_NAME
```

***Note(This will be helpful when your project grows)*** : You can also Define `__init__.py` in `functions/` directory so it becomes the submodule of the `app/` directory so that you can import the Content on `function/` directory into other parts of the project, It'll help you to manage dependency easily in the future.

### The new Layout after making the `functions/` directory as a submodule will be as follows

```bash
app/
├── __init__.py
├── constants.py
└── functions/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── run.py
```

You can learn more about modules in the official Python docs [Python Docs for modules.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Using sys.path.append() Function
   OR
2. Using importlib Packag
   OR
3. Using SourceFileLoader Class

`sys.path.append("module_path")`

```
  # importing module
import sys

# appending a path
sys.path.append('articles')

# importing required module
import gfg
from gfg import GFG

# accessing its content
GFG.method_in()
gfg.method_out()
```

Refer [how-to-import-a-python-module-given-the-full-path](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-import-a-python-module-given-the-full-path/)  :)